# Can't edit xorg.conf in Ubuntu 9.10, is it write protected?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, xorg.conf

My Ubuntu display resolution is 800x600. I want to change it to 1024x768. 
Someone told me to edit `xorg.conf` to achieve this, but I can't save the file. 
How can I edit the file ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use sudo in order to edit xorg.conf. In a terminal you can run `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Or you can use the system configuration tools in the gnome menus, which should prompt you for your password, and allow you to configure your screen without having to edit the file manually.

Comment: i tried from configuer the screen but ther is 800x600 but i want 1024x768 therfore i want to edit it but its rejected to save ....

Comment: @saleem, did you actually try with `sudo` as Justin suggested?

Comment: no how can i try this sudo ? plz tell me complete solution ...

Comment: sudo is a command you run from the terminal - open a terminal and type in "sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf", and press enter to run it. But if configuration is failing by the normal methods, editing the file by hand may not be much help.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem  and I was told xorg.conf is no longer in use.I followed guidance from ubuntu forums and solved the limited resolution in ubuntu 9.10. using xrandr.You may see the following.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8595940

Answer (score 0):

normally you should be able to change the display-resolution by doint this:
Menu System; settings; display and check the resolution-dropdownbox
most time when this fails, you don't have the right graphic-card driver in your system

Comment: i have nvidia geforce fx5200 and i intall it but when i go to display it says that unknown hardeware/..

Comment: ok, please also edit your question and add what you answered me as additional information. In Ubuntu, Go to System - Systemconfiguration or administration (depends on your installed language) - Hardware-drivers. there it will search for drivers and it should ask you, if you want to install the propietary driver for your nvidea-card, do this and after the install restart. then open the displaysettings-selection window (see my previous post) and check what it says now.

Comment: as u say i tried that method too but in hardware-drivers i find 2 drivers both are nvidia . i activat both but seperate time but its still same ...

Comment: The Nvidea-Driver with version 173 or never should work. but perhaps entering this in a console could help, too: sudo nvidia-xconfig

Comment: if it doesn't help, try my next answer I made...

Answer (score 0):

You can completely reconfigure X by doing this:

first change to console by gressing Ctrl/Strg + Alt + F1 and login there.

execute "sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop" (or kdm for KDE)
then "sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg"
then enter this to start your gnome or kde desktop again: "sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start" (or kdm for KDE)

Comment: how to configuer its

Comment: ? "how to configure its ???" normally if you enter these things, it will to everything automatically and reset the x-org configuration. If it still doesn't work, enter sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf and change the values in the monitor-section to something like this: Section "Monitor"
....Identifier    "CM752ET"
....HorizSync     31-101
....VertRefresh    60-160
EndSection